# how to get the data from the android calendar when we add events to it?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am creating an event to a google calendar from inside of my application and as i press the SAVE button it will added to a calendar. what i need is want to fetch that data and sent it to server for future use. Is it possible to get that data??

Thanks

Comment: yes that is possible to retreive events from the calendar using calendar cursor

Comment: how to use calendar cursor ?@AvinashRoy

Comment: Include some code showing what you've already tried. Stack Overflow isn't a free write-code-for-me service. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: did it help u ?? @AnjaliPatel

Comment: no it giving me an error-IllegalArgumentException @AvinashRoy

Comment: where is it giving the error?? @AnjaliPatel

Comment: firstly it giving me an error on  CallHandlerUI that create this class so i commented that Line of code. And i am creating an object of ReadCalendar class and calling a readCalendar method on a button click. so it generating an error IllegalArgumentException  @AvinashRoy

Comment: post the log cat along with ur question @AnjaliPatel

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column displayName
 at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:530)
 at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472) at com.example.admin.calendarevent.ReadCalendar.readCalendar(ReadCalendar.java:28) at com.example.admin.calendarevent.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)  @AvinashRoy

Comment: change this line like this , cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                    (new String[] { "_id", "calendar_displayName", "selected"}), null, null, null); @AnjaliPatel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147783/discussion-between-anjali-patel-and-avinash-roy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class like this for the sole purpose of reading events from ur device calendar :
place an if condition for ur desired events inside the do while loop and store them in an array list and u can send this array to the server by making an http call :

```
 import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.text.format.DateUtils;

    public class ReadCalendar
    {
        static Cursor cursor;

        public static void readCalendar(Context context) {

            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

            // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the

            cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                    (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected"}), null, null, null);

            HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Count="+cursor.getCount());
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("the control is just inside of the cursor.count loop");
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                        String _id = cursor.getString(0);
                        String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
                        Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

                        System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
                        calendarIds.add(_id);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(AssertionError ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // For each calendar, display all the events from the previous week to the end of next week.        
            for (String id : calendarIds) {
                Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
                //Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars").buildUpon();
                long now = new Date().getTime();

                ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 10000);
                ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 10000);

                Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                        new String[]  { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1,
                        null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");

                System.out.println("eventCursor count="+eventCursor.getCount());
                if(eventCursor.getCount()>0)
                {

                    if(eventCursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Object mbeg_date,beg_date,beg_time,end_date,end_time;

                            final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
                            final Date begin = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(1));
                            final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
                            final Boolean allDay = !eventCursor.getString(3).equals("0");

                            /*  System.out.println("Title: " + title + " Begin: " + begin + " End: " + end +
                                        " All Day: " + allDay);
                            */
                            System.out.println("Title:"+title);
                            System.out.println("Begin:"+begin);
                            System.out.println("End:"+end);
                            System.out.println("All Day:"+allDay);

                            /* the calendar control metting-begin events Respose  sub-string (starts....hare) */

                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ");
                            String[] items = p.split(begin.toString());
                            String scalendar_metting_beginday,scalendar_metting_beginmonth,scalendar_metting_beginyear,scalendar_metting_begindate,scalendar_metting_begintime,scalendar_metting_begingmt;

                            scalendar_metting_beginday = items[0];
                            scalendar_metting_beginmonth = items[1];
                            scalendar_metting_begindate = items[2];
                            scalendar_metting_begintime = items[3];
                            scalendar_metting_begingmt = items[4];
                            scalendar_metting_beginyear = items[5];


                            String  calendar_metting_beginday = scalendar_metting_beginday;
                            String  calendar_metting_beginmonth = scalendar_metting_beginmonth.toString().trim();

                            int  calendar_metting_begindate = Integer.parseInt(scalendar_metting_begindate.trim());

                            String calendar_metting_begintime = scalendar_metting_begintime.toString().trim();
                            String calendar_metting_begingmt = scalendar_metting_begingmt;
                            int calendar_metting_beginyear = Integer.parseInt(scalendar_metting_beginyear.trim());


                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginday="+calendar_metting_beginday);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginmonth ="+calendar_metting_beginmonth);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begindate ="+calendar_metting_begindate);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begintime="+calendar_metting_begintime);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begingmt ="+calendar_metting_begingmt);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginyear ="+calendar_metting_beginyear);

                              /* the calendar control metting-begin events Respose  sub-string (starts....ends) */  

                            /* the calendar control metting-end events Respose  sub-string (starts....hare) */

                            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(" ");
                            String[] enditems = p.split(end.toString());
                            String scalendar_metting_endday,scalendar_metting_endmonth,scalendar_metting_endyear,scalendar_metting_enddate,scalendar_metting_endtime,scalendar_metting_endgmt;

                            scalendar_metting_endday = enditems[0];
                            scalendar_metting_endmonth = enditems[1];
                            scalendar_metting_enddate = enditems[2];
                            scalendar_metting_endtime = enditems[3];
                            scalendar_metting_endgmt = enditems[4];
                            scalendar_metting_endyear = enditems[5];


                            String  calendar_metting_endday = scalendar_metting_endday;
                            String  calendar_metting_endmonth = scalendar_metting_endmonth.toString().trim();

                            int  calendar_metting_enddate = Integer.parseInt(scalendar_metting_enddate.trim());

                            String calendar_metting_endtime = scalendar_metting_endtime.toString().trim();
                            String calendar_metting_endgmt = scalendar_metting_endgmt;
                            int calendar_metting_endyear = Integer.parseInt(scalendar_metting_endyear.trim());


                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginday="+calendar_metting_endday);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginmonth ="+calendar_metting_endmonth);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begindate ="+calendar_metting_enddate);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begintime="+calendar_metting_endtime);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_begingmt ="+calendar_metting_endgmt);

                            System.out.println("calendar_metting_beginyear ="+calendar_metting_endyear);

                              /* the calendar control metting-end events Respose  sub-string (starts....ends) */

                            System.out.println("only date begin of events="+begin.getDate());
                            System.out.println("only begin time of events="+begin.getHours() + ":" +begin.getMinutes() + ":" +begin.getSeconds());


                           System.out.println("only date begin of events="+end.getDate());
                            System.out.println("only begin time of events="+end.getHours() + ":" +end.getMinutes() + ":" +end.getSeconds());

                            beg_date = begin.getDate();
                            mbeg_date = begin.getDate()+"/"+calendar_metting_beginmonth+"/"+calendar_metting_beginyear;
                            beg_time = begin.getHours();

                            System.out.println("the vaule of mbeg_date="+mbeg_date.toString().trim());
                            end_date = end.getDate();
                            end_time = end.getHours();


                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_begin_date.add(beg_date.toString());
                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_begin_mdate.add(mbeg_date.toString());

                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_begin_mtime.add(calendar_metting_begintime.toString());

                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_end_date.add(end_date.toString());
                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_end_time.add(end_time.toString());
                            //CallHandlerUI.metting_end_mtime.add(calendar_metting_endtime.toString());

                        }
                        while(eventCursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```